# GitlabCI free shared runners to provision Ubuntu instead of CoreOS?

Tags: ubuntu, docker, gitlab-ci, coreos

I see that GitlabCI now offers free runners for even private repositories in gitlab.com which is great (powered by DigitalOcean). However it seems the default runner is installed in a CoreOS distro which spawns a docker "ruby:2.1" by default.

Is there a way to configure these runners to spawn a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS docker image instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Turns out](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html) that I can use any image name from [the docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/).

So I added this at the top of my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: ubuntu:16.04
```